# How to express the relationship between Factory or Helper class and the objects it can generate with UML class diagram

Tags: java, uml, factory-pattern, class-diagram

Utility/Helper and factory classes are still frequently used in core Java. For instance, `java.util.Collections`, `java.nio.file.Files` are utility classes, `java.nio.files.FileSystems` and `java.nio.files.Paths` are factory classes with static factory methods.

My question is how to make use of UML class diagram to express the relationship between these factory or utility/helper classes and those objects they can generate?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-examples.html

Comment: The examples were about the factory design pattern. But the helper/utility classes contains lots of static methods, which can create other objects. I don't think there is dependency between the helper classes and the generated objects. From the link page u gave there doesn't seem to be similar relationship diagrams

Answer (score 4):

If a class uses another class they connect with a dashed line arrow. By saying uses it means that class A has declared class B inside a method, as parameter or calls it statically.

```
class A {
    public void test(B b) {

    }
}
```

or

```
class A {
    public void test() {
         B b = ...
    }
}
```

or

```
class A {
    public void test() {
        B.teststaticmethod();
    }
}
```

If a class depends on another class they connect with a line arrow. By saying depends it means that class A has class B as private member inside.

```
class A {
    private B b;
}
```

With this knowledge you can model it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples for the factory pattern, like in [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-examples.html)

Helper classes would just use dependencies to the multiplicity of classes they reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the stereotype Create and Utility of UML standard profile fill your need ?

See UML document, section "22.3 Standard Stereotypes":

Create: applies to Usage, A usage dependency denoting that the client classifier creates instances of the supplier classifier.

Utility: applies to Class, A class that has no instances, but rather denotes a named collection of attributes and operations, all of which are static.

[image]